# Can't manipulate global variable (returning undefined)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to display the values obtained from an API using variables year1/2/3 via chartJS. For some reason, when I console log after calling 'getData' the values of var 1/2/3 are undefined.

```
$(function() {

    var year1; /* 1998 */

    function getData() {

      /* Get First Year */
      $.getJSON('https://data.gov.sg/api/action/datastore_search?resource_id=26e9766b-a42d-468c-9c25-88d89b850823&q=1998', function(result) {

        year1 = (result.result.records[0].mobile_penetration_rate);

      })

    }

    getData();

    console.log(year1);

    var ctx = document.getElementById('penetration-chart');
    var myLineChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: ['1998'],
        datasets: [{
          label: '% of Mobile Penetration',
          data: [year1],
          backgroundColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
          ],
          borderColor: [
            'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
            'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
            'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
            'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
            'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
          ],
          borderWidth: 1
        }]
      },
      options: {
        scales: {
          yAxes: [{
            ticks: {
              beginAtZero: true
            }
          }]
        }
      }
    });
  })
```

Logging expected variables after calling getData

Comment: If you console.log year 1 after assigning it your result inside of your result function, does that log the expected value

Comment: yes it does which is strange. I was logging twice (assign value, after getData) but for some reason the latter log throws an undefined but the initial log displayed the expected value.

Comment: Ajax calls are asynchronous that is why you are getting an undefined error when you console log it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The API call is done asynchronously, which means year1 isn't defined by the time it gets to the console.log, which is executed synchronously.  You could wait for your fetch to run and then execute the rest of your code and this will fix your issue : 
(notice returning the $.getJSON, this will return the promise created by .getJSON that the .then will wait for to be resolved before executing )

```
var year1; /* 1998 */

    function getData() {

        /* Get First Year */
        return $.getJSON('https://data.gov.sg/api/action/datastore_search?resource_id=26e9766b-a42d-468c-9c25-88d89b850823&q=1998', function(result) {

             year1 = (result.result.records[0].mobile_penetration_rate);

        })

    }

getData().then(()=> {
    console.log(year1);
    // All other code that depends on year 1
});
```

Comment: wow this was exactly what I needed, especially the promises part I didn't even know of that. since the chart was rendering first I needed to build it after my fetch for the correct data to display, altered your code slightly but it works perfectly now. thanks so much!

Comment: Nice! Glad it helped you out!

Answer (score 1):

You have to console.log inside the success callback method of api call because the `$.getJSON` method calls api asynchronously  and continues the execution without waiting for the API results. Once the response is returned from API call, a callback method is executed with response object

```
$.getJSON('https://data.gov.sg/api/action/datastore_search?resource_id=26e9766b-a42d-468c-9c25-88d89b850823&q=1998', function(result) {

      year1 = (result.result.records[0].mobile_penetration_rate);
      console.log(year1);

    })

getData();
```